# Python script to return result code during grep from a file

Tags: python

I have a python code which should return the exit code 1 or 0 based on the value in the file. The final result should be either 1 or 0 for whole file but not on each line. please let me know how it works.Thanks in advance.

```
def grep(filename, pattern):
    for n,line in enumerate(open(filename)):
        if pattern in line:
            print line,n
            return 1
        else:
            return 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can move the 'return 0' outside for loop and it should work as expected.

```
def grep(filename, pattern):
    for n,line in enumerate(open(filename)):
        if pattern in line:
            print line,n
            return 1
    return 0
```

Comment: can we check multiple patterns and give one result based on that? please add that snippet too if you can . Thanks

Comment: Yes. You can change the if statement.

Comment: " if pattern1 in line or pattern2 in line: "

Comment: The logic depends on what you what to get. Do you want to return 1 if all patterns exist; then use 'and' such as "if pattern1 in line and pattern2 in line". If you want to return 1 if either pattern exists then use 'or'. You can use regex.

Comment: return 1 if any of the pattern exists,0 if all of them doesnot exist